# Struggling with Login API to retrieve bearer token for data API in Azure

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory

So I'm trying to use 2 API's from our external data source, an organization that solely focuses on delivering data to customers (me).

They have 2 different API's:

- A login API: this API is called with basic authentication (username and password) and will provide a bearer token
- An API to extract data and manage filters (this API will require the bearer token acquired through the login API)

Important notes:

- The login API requires a self-signed certificate, I have created a certificate on my PC using openSSL and shared the public key with the external data source.
- I uploaded the .pfx file in Azure (however i cannot set the domain or port number, this seems to be an issue, I can do this in Postman but can't seem to find it in Azure)
- The data source confirmed that the certificate is valid and I am able to use the certificate in Postman but only if i set the correct hostname and also the correct port number (Else i get a TLS error in Postman)
- Everything is working as it should in Postman (I can call the Login API and i can use the bearer token to access and download the data using a json file made for postman that i received from the data source organization)

I uploaded the .pfx certificate in Azure using AppServices > TLS/SSL settings and upload the private certificate, however the hostname it says here is my own database name (I am not sure if this is correct, in Postman i set the hostname when i upload the certificate to be the hostname of our data source with the needed port number)

I tried making a web call in Azure Datafactory, here i've used the correct URL i also use in Postman to access the login API and selected basic authentication and filled in the credentials

However when i try to debug pipeline (only the login web call) it gives the following error:

Error code 2108
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type User configuration issue
DetailsError calling the endpoint '[LINK i put with portnumber, which is correct]'. Response status code: 'NA - Unknown'. More details: Exception message: 'NA - Unknown [ClientSideException] An error occurred while sending the request.'.

Request didn't reach the server from the client. This could happen because of an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation or a timeout.
Source
Pipeline
Punctuality

Am i looking in the wrong direction for this kind of data retrieval? is something going wrong with the certificate? I can't seem to find where i can set the correct hostname and port number (Like i can in Postman when uploading the certificate in .pfx format) Should I use API Management Service rather than Data Factory to make the API call to the external data source?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of regular text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Select the authentication method as [Client Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#client-certificate) in `web` activity settings.

[image]

> Specify base64-encoded contents of a PFX file in Pfx.